# Is there a hook for updated image metadata upon using image editor?

Tags: plugin-development, hooks

When a user uploads an image, I am able to use the `wp_generate_attachment_metadata` hook to know about all the thumbnail locations.

When I use Wordpress to Edit Image (to scale, resize, etc), I can not figure a similar hook. If I hook to `wp_save_image_editor_file`, I can do `$metadata = wp_get_attachment_metadata($post_id);` which always gets me the previous iteration. So if I edit an image two times, `$metadata` would contain the sizes of the last edit. Not the one that just completed.

I tried this code, but it doesn't even fire:

```php
add_filter('wp_edited_image_metadata', 'edited_image_metadata', 10, 3);
function edited_image_metadata($new_image_meta, $new_attachment_id, $attachment_id)
{
  error_log("EDITED FILE METADATA: $new_attachment_id | $attachment_id");
}
```